# Can't boot after kernel/package update - snd-hda intel - HDMI/DP requires biding with gfx driver

Tags: linux-kernel, boot

Using Tuxedo OS on a macbook air 2013. Been working great, but once I allowed the OS to update the kernel I got this:
[boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T37sl.jpg)

I have tried adding "acpi=!Darwin" to kernel, which removed the irq 0 message. Howevern I still have the "requires binding with gfx driver" message and can't boot. Tried switching kernel as well with no avail.

[lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrSq.jpg)

Would highly appreciate any help. I can currently only access grub and root terminal.